# How to locate a string then get the following characters up to a certain character

Tags: text-extraction, data-extraction

Here's an example input:

```
<div><a class="document-subtitle category" href="/store/apps/category/GAME_ADVENTURE"> <span itemprop="genre">Adventure</span> </a>  </div> <div> </div>
```

The string i'm trying to locate is this:

```
document-subtitle category" href="/store/apps/category/
```

and I want to extract the characters that follows that string up until the end of the href attribute (**">**).

In this case, my output should be:

```
GAME_ADVENTURE
```

My input file is guaranteed to have only one string that matches exactly to:

```
document-subtitle category" href="/store/apps/category/
```

What's the *easiest* way of achieving this?

Comment: Is there a particular programming language?

Comment: ^ Nope. I'm after the easiest way to achieve it.

Comment: Do you try or did anything work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class ExtractData {
  public static String matcher = "document-subtitle category\" href=\"/store/apps/category/";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String filePath = args[0];
    String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath)));
    int startIndex = content.indexOf(matcher);
    int endIndex = content.indexOf("\">", startIndex);
    String category = content.substring(startIndex + matcher.length(), endIndex);
    System.out.println("category is " + category);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this particular case, this is how I would do it in java:

```
private static final String _control = "document-subtitle category";
    private static final String _href = "href";

    private String getCategoryFromInput(String input) {
        if (input.contains(_control)) {
            int hrefStart = input.indexOf(_href);

            int openQuote = input.indexOf('"', hrefStart + 1);

            int endQuote = input.indexOf('"', openQuote + 1);

            String chunk = input.substring(openQuote, endQuote);

            int finalDelimeter = chunk.lastIndexOf("/");

            return chunk.substring(finalDelimeter);
        } else {
            return "";
        }

    }
```